# problems getting data from localhost:8888 in objective c using json

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c, json

I am trying to use a server for the first time.

I have downloaded MAMP and have a local sever on my mac http://localhost:8888

I have a php file jsontest.php that shows my data from a SQL database

```
<?php
   // Database credentials
   $host = 'localhost'; 
   $db = 'json'; 
   $uid = 'json'; 
   $pwd = 'json1';


    // Connect to the database server   
    $link = mysql_connect($host, $uid, $pwd) or die("Could not connect");

   //select the json database
   mysql_select_db($db) or die("Could not select database");

   // Create an array to hold our results
   $arr = array();
   //Execute the query
   $rs = mysql_query("SELECT id,userid,firstname,lastname,email FROM users");

   // Add the rows to the array 
   while($obj = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {
   $arr[] = $obj;
   }


   echo '{"users":'.json_encode($arr).'}';

?>
```

When i go to to http://localhost:8888/jsontest.php (the jsontest.php file is stored in MAMP/htdocs) I can see my data:

```
{"users":[{"id":"1","userid":"fhardy","firstname":"Frank","lastname":"Hardy","email":"fhardy@hauntedclock.com"},{"id":"2","userid":"jhardy","firstname":"Joe","lastname":"Hardy","email":"jhardy@hauntedclock.com"},{"id":"3","userid":"ndrew","firstname":"Nancy","lastname":"Drew","email":"ndrew@hauntedclock.com"},{"id":"4","userid":"sdoo","firstname":"Scooby","lastname":"Doo","email":"sdoo@mysterymachine.com"}]}
```

I then use the following objective c code to read from this server:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost:8888/jsontest.php"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil]; // 

NSLog(@"jsonArray: %@", jsonArray);
```

But the app crashes with the error

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'
```

I know the error is coming from my server as it works with the server from a tutorial. But i cannot get it to work with my local server on my mac. I have tried using just http://localhost/jsontest.php but it still doesn't work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### ***Instead of localhost, put your IP.***

*That's it...*

[*This is how you will get your local IP*](http://osxdaily.com/2010/11/21/find-ip-address-mac/).

[*Also check this*](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-Your-IP-Address-on-a-Mac)

Comment: @Amy : while searching you should have searched [how to run localhost website in iphone](https://www.google.com.kw/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=how%20to%20run%20localhost%20website%20in%20iphone). First link is your answer...